# WSUS powershell unapproved declined update

Tags: windows, powershell

I made a script to decline superseded updates automatically.

I made a loop to find the superseding updates for each superseded updates, and the script decline the superseded update if he find the superseding.

But if the script don't find the superseding updates in the not declined updates, i want him to check in the declined updates, and if he found the superseding updates in the declined, i want the script to unapprouved the superseding declined update.

I tried a lot of things to set declined updates to unapproved by powershell but i can't make it working ...

I found these two commands on internet who works for some peoples :

```
Approve-WsusUpdate -Update (Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateId -------) -Action NotApproved -TargetgroupName "Tous les ordinateurs"
```

Error : The desired update approval is not valid for the specified computer target group.

```
Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateId ------- | % {$_.Update.Approve("NotApproved","Tous les ordinateurs")}
```

Error: Surcharge introuvable pour « Approve » et le nombre d'arguments « 2 ».

I can manually unapproved updates from the GUI for the group "Tous les ordinateurs", so i think it's possible to do it in powershell :D

Thanks for your help :D

EDIT :

I found something using procmon to find what happens on system when i approved a declined update, and i found in the softwaredisctibution.log these lines :

2023-11-23 12:23:48.269 UTC Change  w3wp.83 DBConnection.OnReceivingInfoMessage Successfully deployed deployment(Block) of 2021-09 Dynamic Update for Windows 10 Version 20H2 for ARM64-based Systems (KB5005714) by ********** UpdateID:151EE292-A2AA-4881-804A-D7DE07AB20D0 Revision Number:202 TargetGroup:Unassigned Computers

2023-11-23 12:23:48.300 UTC Change  w3wp.83
DBConnection.OnReceivingInfoMessage Deleted deployment(Block) of 2021-09 Dynamic Update for Windows 10 Version 20H2 for ARM64-based Systems (KB5005714) by ********** UpdateID:151EE292-A2AA-4881-804A-D7DE07AB20D0 Revision Number:202 TargetGroup:Unassigned Computers

When i approved the declined update by the GUI, we can see that WSUS approved for deployement to "Unassigned Computers", and immediatly delete the deployment ...

Now i have to find out how to do this in powershell :D

Comment: I try to edit because i forgot to say Hello but stackoverflow don't take my changes so "Hello" :D

Comment: Try to use the [`-action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/updateservices/approve-wsusupdate?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-action) parameter and specify the `NotApproved` value for it within the `Approve-Wsus` command. See if that makes the switch for you.

Comment: Hi, that's what i do in the first command i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution :

I approved for install the declined update to the unassigned computers group, and after this i can set NotApproved to -Action.

```
Approve-WsusUpdate -Update (Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateId $updateIn.Id.UpdateId.Guid) -Action Install -TargetGroupName "Ordinateurs non attribués"

Approve-WsusUpdate -Update (Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateId $updateIn.Id.UpdateId.Guid) -Action NotApproved -TargetGroupName "Ordinateurs non attribués"
```

But now i have another problem  :D
When an update is assigned to notapproved from the declined, it's possible that there is another declined update who supersede this update in declined.

How can i update my foreach ($updateIn in $allUpdates) with the new informations?

EDIT :

I solved my problem with a simple "while" :D
I add a variable to check if updates was modified (set to declined or to reinstate).

```
#variables set at 1 for the while execute the first time
$updatesReinstate = 1
$updatesDeclined = 1
while ($updatesReinstate -ne 0 -or $updatesDeclined -ne 0)
{
#Reset to 0 the variables in the while
$updatesReinstate = 0
$updatesDeclined = 0
...
Approve-WsusUpdate -Update (Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateId $updateIn.Id.UpdateId.Guid) -Action Install -TargetGroupName "Ordinateurs non attribués"
Approve-WsusUpdate -Update (Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateId $updateIn.Id.UpdateId.Guid) -Action NotApproved -TargetGroupName "Ordinateurs non attribués"
...
}
```

So i made a while with this variable and i put all my script in it, and it works fine :)

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution using the `-Action` and related value of `NotApproved`. I suggest you [edit] this answer and add in the additional `while` loop logic used to handle the superseded part as this may be what other people need in the future that come looking for a similar solution.